# Языковые версии сайта

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Ребята, привет всем!

Дело такое. Сейчас есть сайт на русском языке. Нужно, сделать украинскую версию по умолчанию, а русский - опционально, так как сайт рассчитан на украинское пространство.

Как вообще это делать? В какую сторону «рыть»? Быть может, есть какое-то универсальное средство для этих дел?

Comment: Гуглите «многоязычность сайт php».

Comment: Технология какая? PHP?

Comment: спасибо хоть не на россиянском

Comment: извините за "российском". украинец я, русский язык по самообразованию выучил, как видите не без ляпов. Да, сайт на PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Изначально открывается украинская версия. При нажатии на русский флажок в cookie ставиться `lang=ru`. На сервере: если кукишек установлен, то отдать русский сайт.

Comment: Зачем так некрасиво?)) можно же смотреть по айпи? если с россии сразу русский выдавать) и главное мод реврайт настроить) чтоб ссылка была вида sitename.ua/ru

Comment: @ToRcH565


> украинскую версию по дефолту,

и

> т.к. сайт рассчитан на украинское пространство

Comment: да если б я мог вот так "бахбах и в дамках". Я же про это ничего незнаю. Поэтому и попросил дать пинок в нужном направлении. Почитать, вникнуть в саму суть, что куда.

Comment: 1. Гуглите по запросу cookie. Изучаете как использовать

2. Найдёте в инете как считать куки используя php

3. Здесь показывают как возвращать нужный перевод http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller#Model-View-Controller-Language_.28MVC-L.29

4. И всё-таки: https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0%20php&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.bGE&fp=5ae7de352b0af4d8&biw=1920&bih=968&pf=p&pdl=300

Comment: Спасибо!))) Иду грызть.

Comment: @mrDimitry , Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @mrDimitry а вот ваши единственные 17 очков вы зря отдали. Они бы вам ещё пригодились. Жаль возвращать нельзя - так бы 27 вернул

Answer (score 0):

В php много механизмов работающих как с текстом так и с адресами, вариант локализации сайта:
Создание отдельного раздела или поддомена на нужном языке.
Поддержка языковых фраз: вы выносите все "слова, фразы тексты" в отдельные файлы шаблона и подключаете нужные языки.
С базой данных: вы создаете отдельный контент или даже отдельные таблицы для языков.